# Can I read the track number of a song from OneDrive using the LiveConnect API?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, onedrive, liveconnect

The [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#audio) provides the title, artist, album, and picture for each track. However, I don't see any way to retrieve the track number.

I know that OneDrive has this information:

[image: OneDrive web app]

Is it possible to retrieve a track number for a song directly from OneDrive? Or do I need to parse the id3 tags myself, despite other relevant metadata being available through the LiveConnect API?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the returned [audio object reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631831.aspx), it doesn't appear to be a provided field in the response.